# I am failing to calculate prevalence using this code

Tags: r

I tried using the code below but prevalence keeps returning NA:

```
S1 %>% 
  group_by(Year, Province, Test) %>% 
  summarise(Prevalence = sum(Result)/n())
```

The prevalence keeps returning an NA for all the variables even after trying all other options

Comment: Don't put sample data in comments, there are not good formatting options. Instead edit it into your question.

Comment: if `any(is.na(S1$Result)` returns `TRUE`, go ahead and specify `na.rm = TRUE` in `mean()`.

Comment: try: `summarise(prevalence = sum(vs, na.rm = TRUE)/n())`